# Change the name of the output file to servername

Tags: powershell

I want to dynamically output the file using the name of the server its been run instead of specifying what name to use. as i want to run the code on multiple servers using multi-instance approach.

```
$OutFile = "C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\AoN Project\Execute\Output.csv"
$Header = "FolderPath,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags"
Del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$RootPath = "C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\Operations Orchestration"

$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
        $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change $OutFile depending on name of server. You can do that using MachineName property of Environment class:

```
$OutFile = "C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\AoN Project\Execute\$([Environment]::MachineName).csv"
```